# Building docker image for multi module project pushing jars to classpath

Tags: dockerfile, maven-plugin, jib, maven-jib

I am trying to create docker image for my project which is having multiple modules. The need is to build the image in such a way that the image should contain the child module jar in a given classpath. The structure of my project is

```
 parent_project
 |
 |
   module-1
   |
   pom.xml
   |
   module-2
   |
   pom.xml
|
pom.xml
```

So ideally when the build happens it the image should have a classpath where both modules jar are to be present. But with the below given pom.xml I am seeing the images when build are overwritten with latter build. So one image is build with first module jar and second image is formed with second module jar thus final image contains only the later jar.

part of pom.xml

```
<modules>
    <module>xxxxxxxxx_m1</module>
    <module>xxxxxxxxx_m2</module>
</modules>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>xxxyyyy****_base_image</image>
                </from>
                <container>
                    <entrypoint>INHERIT</entrypoint>
                    <appRoot>/etc/plugin</appRoot>
                    <environment>
                        <CLASSPATH>
                            /etc/plugin/classpath/xxxxxxxxx_m1-SNAPSHOT.jar
                            /etc/plugin/classpath/xxxxxxxxx_m2-SNAPSHOT.jar
                        </CLASSPATH>
                    </environment>
                </container>
                <containerizingMode>packaged</containerizingMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am building the image by providing following command :-

```
   mvn package jib:build -Dimage=<base_image>:<tag_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project setup makes sense only when each of the two modules `xxxxx_m1` and `xxxxx_m2` is a standalone app that has its own main class and can run independently of each other, each with

- `java -cp <xxxxx_m1-SNAPSHOT:others...> <main class in xxxxx_m1>`
- `java -cp <xxxxx_m2-SNAPSHOT:others...> <main class in xxxxx_m2>`

That is, the setup makes sense only when you intend to create two separate and independent images for two different apps. In this case, Jib is working as intended and you are producing two different container images. It's just that by saying `-Dimage` (equivalent to `-Djib.to.image`), you are giving the same *target* image name for the two images, so one ends up overwriting the other in the end, which doesn't make sense. If this is really the case, you just need to define `<to><image>` differently in each module. (You can have `<pluginManagement>` in the root `pom.xml` to declare Jib version and common Jib `<configuration>`, and then define module-specific Jib `<configuration>` in each sub-module `pom.xml`. I will point you to an example at the end, so keep reading.)

But I am not sure if this is what you intended, because it sounds like you want to see both modules inside a single image. Perhaps it's that `_m2` is the app with a main class and `_m1` is a JAR library that `_m2` depends on? (That is, `pom.xml` in `_m2` defined `_m1` as a dependency?) In this case,

- root `pom.xml`: [define `<pluginManagement>`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/4e5d44c5aead88b2836b41371cee57d6f70f1c2b/examples/multi-module/pom.xml#L38-L47) to declare the Jib version
- `_m1` `pom.xml` (dependency library): [set `<skip>true`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/4e5d44c5aead88b2836b41371cee57d6f70f1c2b/examples/multi-module/shared-library/pom.xml#L23-L24) to suppress Jib image building
- `_m2` `pom.xml`: optionally define `_m2`-specific configuration

Take a look at this [multi-module example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/examples/multi-module). It has three modules, where Jib runs in `hello-service` and `name-service` to build two images, while `name-service` defines the `shared-library` module as a dependency.

In either case, I don't see a reason to set `<containerizingMode>packaged` or `<environment><CLASSPATH>` unless your app is specifically written to read the environment variable or requires to run inside a JAR (e.g., need to read JAR manifest). The default "exploded" containerizing mode is much more efficient, so just try running Jib without these.

Comment: thanks Chanseok, the info was insightful but still not solves my issue. To give more info m1 and m2 are basically modules which are customising few functionalities already available. These are needed by parent project to make the functionality to work. Both the module m1 and m2 don't have any main class in them. So you can take them as library jars which are basically customised and are to be placed at the given classpath.

Comment: Are you saying the root project is a main app that has a main class? If so, that is not the correct way to set up a multi-module project. The root POM should just be a aggregator project whose packaing type is `pom`. Your main app should be another sub-module. That is, there should be three sub-modules, and the main sub-module should depend on m1 and m2.